# Docker with php8.2(php82) curl sends 50% times with "53" error

Tags: php, docker, curl, alpine-linux

**1. I use docker with alpine**
(VERSION_ID=3.19.0
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.19")

**2.There i install from docker compose:**

```
RUN apk upgrade && apk update
RUN apk add php82
RUN apk add php82-curl
```

COPY php.ini /etc/php82/php.ini (the same file that gives me after installing php, but I changed "short_open_tag = On")

**3. After that i go into the container and try php** (PHP version 8.2)
The script I'm using worked fine on a simple PHP host, fine
Post to console:

```
**/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/poster_bot/du/index.php**
```

at this step i have problem, this line activate php script to send curl to telegram api, **50% of activate this script are executed, 50 - not**.
I start find log errors - empty (or ok, or empty response)
I add curl_error and curl_errno and find false and **56 error**
This CURL and code with errors checkers underneath:

//send function to telegram

```
function post($url, $postContent){  
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postContent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: multipart/form-data']);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    logtxt(json_encode($postContent));

    if (json_encode($result) === 'false') {
        logtxt('-----');
        //throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
        logtxt(curl_error($curl));
        logtxt(curl_errno($curl));
        logtxt('-----');
    }
    logtxt(json_encode($result));
    logtxt($result);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
```

log.txt

```
26.01.24 18:26:36 -----
26.01.24 18:26:36
26.01.24 18:26:36 56
26.01.24 18:26:36 -----
26.01.24 18:26:36 false
26.01.24 18:26:36
```

**4. At this point i'm stuck.** This error i supposed is **(CURLE_RECV_ERROR (56) Failure with receiving network data.)** I try open, forwarding ports on docker - no effect, check firewall on mother PC (Windows 10) - no effect. I don't know why 50% of requests are fulfilled. Why is the remaining 50% not being executed?

After I try to downgrade to PHP 7.4 Alpine. I have got the same program behavior. BUT the error has changed. I got error curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream. Then i gave up, and start topic on stackoverflow (.

**Thanks for attention, and thank you.**

Comment: I have not solve this, but i found this problem is on host pc or telegram servers
I was 100% sure that everything was sending from the host PC since everything worked recently. There appeared additional data - OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054. I tried to find solution but nothing. Sending with delay not helps.
I will solve this sending that it several times through the cycle